# Binding two function. Alternative syntax

Tags: haskell

```
f = do 
  let off =  getOff >>= computeOffset

getOff :: M Int
   computeOffset :: Int -> Int
```

`M` is a monad.

It doesn't look nicely. Can I improve it using sugar syntax?

Comment: (1) Your do-block isn't valid, as it ends with a `let` line. Also, with the types you mention, `getOff >>= computeOffset` won't typecheck. You should fix those issues in order to get suggestions more relevant to what you are actually trying to do. (2) That said, perhaps you are just looking for `f = getOff >>= computeOffset`, which doesn't involve any sugar at all.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding into `do` syntax could be done in the following way, starting with:

```hs
getOff >>= computeOffset
```

There is a parameter being passed to `computeOffset` which is hidden. It may help to show what that looks like explicitly before going to `do` syntax:

```hs
getOff >>= \off -> computeOffset off
```

Now you can write the `do` syntax by taking `off` in the first line, then using it in the second.

```hs
do
    off <- getOff
    computOffset off
```

Answer (score 0):

If `computeOffset` has type `Int -> Int`, and that you want to map it to the result of `getOff`, you can use `fmap`:

```
f :: M Int
f = fmap computeOffset getOff
```

... or, alternatively, with the applicative notation (pretty much the same)

```
f :: M Int
f = computeOffset <$> getOff
```